# Compare coefficients across different regressions

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to compare the coefficients of two linear regressions with the same variables, but run for different subgroups. I want to check if the coefficients in my model 1 are equal to my coefficients in my model 2. I need to know for each coefficient.

My reproducible data :

```
Data <- data.frame(
gender = sample (c("men", "women"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
var1 = sample (c("value1", "value2"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
var2 = sample (c("valueA", "valueB"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
y = sample(0:10, 2000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I run the two regressions :

```
men <- subset(Data, gender =="men")
women <- subset(Data, gender =="women")

lm.men <- lm(y~var1+var2, data = men)
summary(lm.men)
lm.women <- lm(y~var1+var2, data = women)
summary(lm.women)
```

Basically, I want to test if:

- coefficient `var1` in `lm.men` = coefficient `var1` in `lm.women`
- coefficient `var2` in `lm.men` = coefficient `var2` in `lm.women`

I can't use the `anova()` function, because my two samples are different. I think I should apply an F-test but I can't find a function for this test.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem ?

Comment: This is more of a "Cross-Validated" question, and one that [already has an answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/what-is-the-correct-way-to-test-for-significant-differences-between-coefficients)

Comment: oops. at least my answer gives R-coding details that aren't included in the CV answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Barker points out in comments, the statistical part of this question is [already answered on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/what-is-the-correct-way-to-test-for-significant-differences-between-coefficients); I'll add some R-coding details here.

In order to answer these questions ("do the effects of `var1` and `var2` differ significantly between men and women?), fit a model with variable-by-gender interactions and test the interaction terms.

```
Data <- data.frame(
     gender = sample (c("men", "women"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
     var1 = sample (c("value1", "value2"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
    var2 = sample (c("valueA", "valueB"), 2000, replace = TRUE),
    y = sample(0:10, 2000, replace = TRUE)
 )
 mm <- lm(y~(var1+var2)*gender,Data)
```

Here are the interaction terms:

```
interax <- c("var1value2:genderwomen","var2valueB:genderwomen")
printCoefmat(coef(summary(mm))[interax,])
##                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## var1value2:genderwomen  0.20144    0.28241  0.7133   0.4758
## var2valueB:genderwomen -0.15423    0.28266 -0.5456   0.5854
```

Comment: Many thanks @Ben ! Could you just help me to interpret correctly the results ? In your sample, should I conclude that the var1 differ significantly between men and women because the `Pr(>|t|)` is higher than 0.10 ?

Comment: These are standard p-values for the test of the null hypothesis that there is no interaction (i.e., that the effects of the variables are the same for both genders).  Large p-values mean that the null hypothesis cannot be rejected (if this is unfamiliar to you, you should definitely improve/refresh your basic statistical knowledge before analyzing data ...)

Comment: Also, I would certainly hope that the difference between genders came back as insignificant in that example since all the values were just randomly sampled.